# Call to super must be first statement in the constructor, but it is

Tags: java, constructor, super

I keep getting an error saying that "call to super must be the first statement in the constructor".

The problem is that it *is* the first statement in my constructor.

```
public void CheckingAccountCustomer(int a){
    super(n, p, b);
    accountNo = a;
}
```

And here is my superclass for this as well.

```
public void customer(String n, int p, double b){
    name = n;
    pin = p;
    balance = b;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The interesting thing here is that, since these aren't constructors, the call to `super()` is trying to call the constructor of the parent class from inside a method in the child. The error message says "Its not the first line in the child's constructor." That is true but not terribly helpful. Maybe a message like "Call to super not in constructor" would be nice.

Comment: I was definitely not expecting to have answers this quickly. Of course, it was a simple fix that I was too blind to see. But still, thank you to all.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This code

```
public void customer(String n, int p, double b){
```

is not a constructor.  Constructors don't have return types, e.g. `void`.  Assuming your class name is `customer`:

```
public customer(String n, int p, double b){
```

This applies to `CheckingAccountCustomer` too.

Comment: Note that while `customer` (with a small C) is a valid class name, it is frowned upon. By convention, class names must start with a capital letter (`Customer`) while method names start with a small letter.

Answer (score 8):

```
public void CheckingAccountCustomer(int a){
```

That's not a constructor since it states it has a `void` return type. It's just a method of the same name as the class.  Get rid of the return type.

```
public CheckingAccountCustomer(int a){
```

Comment: I will vote up every answer you've ever given, if you simply change the wording to "You call that a constructor? THIS is a constructor!"

Comment: @ChrisCooney: I wish I were as clever as you! :)

Comment: @PhilMeyer: don't feel bad. I'll bet most of us tripped on these "pseudoconstructors" when starting out. Bet you'll never do it again though.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void CheckingAccountCustomer(int a)
```

This is a method not a constructor, since it has a return type.

Answer (score 2):

The *constructor* is used to create an *instance of that Class*, so it make no sense if it will let the user to change the return type (it can be dangerous too). That's why constructors has **no** return type.

As others have already answered, remove the return type and it'll become a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors never return something (either void or Object type).

```
public void CheckingAccountCustomer(int a){
    super(n, p, b);
    accountNo = a;
}
```

thus is not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your "constructor" is really a constructor.**

With the monumentious amounts of boilerplate bullshit in Java it is a wonder to me why constructors don't have a "constructor" keyword. I mean, Java doesn't have a problem with being overly verbose, yet likes to be terse in places where being verbose would be a good idea.

//:WRONG://

```
@Service
public class      EmployeeServiceImpl 
       implements EmployeeServiceInterface
{

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository ;

    /** Constructor **/

    public EmployeeServiceImpl saveEmployee(
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository
    ){
        super(); //:No blank line allowed? ://
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository ;

    }

}
```

//:FIXED://

```
@Service
public class      EmployeeServiceImpl 
       implements EmployeeServiceInterface
{

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository ;

    /** Constructor **/

    public EmployeeServiceImpl(
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository
    ){
        super(); //:No blank line allowed? ://
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository ;

    }
}
```

Because java allows overloading, it didn't pick up on this mistake. Because right below my constructor was this:

```
@Override
public EmployeeDAO saveEmployee( EmployeeDAO employee ){

        return employeeRepository.save( employee ) ;

}
```